# TypeError: Unsupported command argument type: Resque::Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque, redisclient

I am using resque gem - `(1.27.4)`
I upgraded my `redis-rb` gem to `5.0.6` from `3.3.5`.

In my rails application, I initialize the Resque's redis instance as follows:

```
Resque.redis = Redis.new(creds)
```

Now I understand that in this version  redis is using a redis-client gem:

```
    redis (5.0.6)
      redis-client (>= 0.9.0)
    redis-client (0.14.0)
```

And I understand that this is very strict about the datatype and has strict checks as follows:

```
case element
  when String
    element
  when Integer, Float, Symbol
    element.to_s
  else
    raise TypeError, "Unsupported command argument type: #{element.class}"
  end
end
```

My doubt is that - is there any workaround here, I don't want to upgrade the resque and I need this version of redis for reconnect attempts purposes.

Comment: What is `creds`?

Comment: host, port, db in a hash.